# Is "In movie and TV" correct?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

In German you may say something like

> In Film und Fernsehen spielen Schauspieler.

which translates verbatim to English as

> In movie and TV actors act.

1. While the German version sounds familiar to me as a native speaker, is the English version correct?
2. What grammatical role does "movie and TV" occupy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say "in television and film", but if you stick with the word 'movie' I think the correct usage would be "in movies and TV".

Comment: Yes. _Film_ and _television_ can both be used as mass nouns, but I can't think of a comparable use of _movie_.

Comment: @Colin.  Motion pictures.  Movie is a colloquial version of motion pictures.

Comment: @ColinFine I force myself to translate the German "Film" to "movie" and **not** "film" but "film" seems alright here then. I'll have to learn when to use "movie" and when "film", apparently.

Comment: @StevenLittman: I'm well aware what _movie_ means. I meant that I can't think of a use of it **as a mass noun**.

Comment: @cad: in most uses, they are interchangeable, but as I say, _film_ can be used as a mass noun, while _movie_ cannot. (_Film_ can also be used as a count noun, of course). Also, _movie_ is considerably more common in the US than the UK - GLOwBe shows 67K instances of _film_ in the US against 61K of _movie_; but 95K vs 33K for the UK.